# BeautifulSoup/Python/HTML - Return the div class right after a specific div class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Example:

```
<div class="label">Employee Count</div>
<div class="field">331,000</div>
```

How can I use beautiful soup (or a different python lib) to search an HTML file for "Employee Count" then return the value (331,000) that comes right after it?

Using

```
result = soup.body.find(text='Employee Count')
```

I can find Employee Count, but how can I return the field right after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `div` element with `Employee Count` text and get the [next sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
soup.find('div', text='Employee Count').find_next_sibling().text
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> data = """
... <body>
... <div class="label">Employee Count</div>
... <div class="field">331,000</div>
... </body>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
>>> soup.find('div', text='Employee Count').find_next_sibling().text
331,000
```